# Spring.NET & Constructor Interceptors

Tags: .net, constructor, aop, spring.net

I'm trying to do some AOP over objects at construction time, and found IConstructorInterceptor, which would be perfect for what I want but it [doesn't appear to work](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPRNET-215) (in version 1.2 at least).

I've also looked at both the IObjectPostProcessor & the IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessor, but I can't find any way to do processing on an object around construction time... The PostProcessPropertyValues method on the IInstantiationAwareObjectPostProcessor is close, but it only passes through setter injected properties not the constructor arg values...

Specifically what I want is a reference to an object just after instantiation and at the same time, references to the objects that were injected into the constructor. Is there any way to do this, or is my best bet to just switch to setter injection & use the post processor or a MethodInterceptor?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: No. Unfortunately the functionality just isn't in the current version (nor in the up coming 1.3), & I never found a better work around than what I mentioned above.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106701/inheritancebasedaopconfigurer-using-runtime-constructor-arguments

Answer (score 0):

AOP proposes call interception, not dependency injection. Using Spring.Net you can use seters or constructors to perform any dependency injection. For your post and comments, it supposed to work.

On Spring.Net initialization pipeline, first step analyse dependency graph, perform any object creation and set all dependencies. After that, if your class implement "Spring.Objects.Factory.IInitializingObject", the method "void AfterPropertiesSet();" is called. Other way to perform that is using your object configuration, you may setting init-method on object node.
This behavior is based in IoC/DI concepts.

Maybe you needs create a specific factory object. To perform that, your factory must implement Spring.Objects.Factory.IFactoryObject interface. That helps container to delegate for you the object creation (properties and constructors on this configuration are for your factory).

Best Regards