# InheritanceBasedAopConfigurer using runtime constructor arguments

Tags: c#, spring.net

I've got a (prototype) class owned by the Spring.NET context, created with an AutoProxy with runtime constructor arguments. It get's instantiated like this.

```
var context = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
var myClass = context.GetObject("myclass", new object[]{ myRuntimeConstructorArgument }) as MyClass;
```

This class has some inner logic going, where it catches an event that gets handled by a class method, like this:

```
// MyClass owned by Spring.NET context
public class MyClass {

  // InnerObject not owned by Spring context
  private InnerObject innerobject;

  // argument object not owned by Spring context
  public MyClass(ObjectNotOwnedBySpring myRuntimeConstructorArgument) {
     ...
     this.innerobject = new InnerObject();
     this.innerobject.SomeEvent += this.handleSomeEvent;
  }

  // I would like to intercept this event handler
  public virtual void handleMyEvent (object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I'm trying to use AOP to remove an abstraction leak (caused by a bug in an external component), by intercepting the handleMyEvent method.  Because Spring.Aop uses a proxy based approach to intercept method calls, inner method calls don't get intercepted. I get that part.

If I understand the [documentation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxy-mechanism) correctly, that's where the **InheritanceBasedAopConfigurer** comes into play, by using a 'true' inheritance based AOP mechanism. From the documentation:

> Interception advice is added directly in the method body before invoking the base class method.

Exactly what I need!

Unfortunatly, I can't get the InheritanceBasedAopConfigurer get to play nicely with the runtime constructor arguments:

> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectCreationException: Error creating object with name 'myclass' > defined in 'file [spring-aop-config.xml] line 36' : Could not resolve matching constructor.

Is runtime constructor arguments not supported by the InheritanceBasedAopConfigurer ? Or is this a wrong use case for the InheritanceBasedAopConfigurer ?

Comment: Firstly: your code is not valid (`public MyClass` should be `public class MyClass`). Please ensure that the code you provide is valid because error messages like these are often caused by small details. Second: what is the type of `myRuntimeConstructorArgument`? Could you provide the declaration of this variable?

Comment: Sorry about the class declaration, I fixed that in the original post.

Comment: A clear example of *myRuntimeConstructorArgument* could be just a String, that is known at runtime. But it really could be any object (or multiple objects).

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728533/spring-net-constructor-interceptors

Comment: I think this is a known issue in spring.net which has not yet (1.3.2) been resolved: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-215